# Port allocation when running build job in Jenkins

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, jenkins, apache-kafka

My project is structured in such a way that the build job in Jenkins is triggered from a push to Git. As part of my application logic, I spin up kafka and elastic search instances to be used in my test cases downstream.

The issue I have right now is, when a developer pushes his changes to Git, it triggers a build in Jenkins which in turn runs our code and spawns kafka broker in localhost:9092 and elastic search in localhost:9200.

When another developer working on some other change simultaneously, pushes his code, it triggers the build job again and tries to spin up another instance of kafka/elastic search but fails with the exception “Port already in use”.

I am looking at options on how to handle this scenario.

Will running these instances inside of docker container help to some extent? How do I handle the port issue in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes dockerizing these instances can indeed help as you can spawn them multiple times.

You could create a docker container per component including your application and then let them talk to each other by linking them or using docker-compose

That way you would not have to expose the ports to the "outside" world but keep it internal within the docker environment.

That way you would not have the “Port already in use”. The only problem is memory in that case. e.g. if 100 pushes are done to the git repo, you might run out of memory...

Comment: You would set the number of executors to control resources - or could set to 1 to avoid the issue altogether but I assume the OP wants to be able to do concurrent builds. If you want to restrict just one job, you can look into something like [Build Blocker](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin)

Comment: @ivonet Thanks for responding. How does the port mechanism work in that case? If one developer pushes his change the zookeeper instance of his docker container would use 2181 of host machine and what happens when there is a concurrent push from another developer?

Comment: Given that my docker-compose.yml looks like below    `kafka:
    image: "wurstmeister/kafka:0.10.2.0"
    ports:
     - "9092:9092"
    hostname: kafka
    links: 
     - zookeeper
    environment:
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=kafka
     - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
     - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT=9092
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"`